# longest palindrome subsequence using top down approach

Tags: c++

```
int lps[13][13]={0,0};
int calculate_lps(char *p,int start,int end) {
    int i=start;
    int j=end;
    if(lps[i][j]==0) {
        if(i==j)
            return lps[i][j]=1;
        else if(p[i]==p[j] && i+1==j)
            return lps[i][j]=2;
        else if(p[i]==p[j])
            return lps[i][j]=calculate_lps(p,i+1,j-1)+2;
        else
            lps[i][j]=max(calculate_lps(p,i+1,j),calculate_lps(p,i,j-1));
    }
    else return lps[i][j];
}
int main() {
    char seq[] = "GEEKSFORGEEKS";
    calculate_lps(seq, 0, 12);
    cout<<lps[0][12];
    return 0;
}
```

I tried top down approach in dynamic programming for longest palindrome subsequence but the ouput that I am getting is 0.

What am I missing here?  How do I correct my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not return anything in the last inner else (`else lps ...`).

Comment: So naive of me -.- . @Aconcagua thanks it worked.

Comment: which compiler are u using @BOTJr. , Almost all latest compilers warn during compilation for missing return statements.

Comment: Gcc -4.9.2 , i was running my code on `codechef.com/ide` .